# How to install or go to fastboot mode if my phone is stuck in animation boot and has no fastboot in it?

Tags: recovery-mode, fastboot, system, xiaomi

---

Im using Xiaomi redmi 1s and I modified something on the system, after rebooting it, It was stuck at the animation boot. I can only go to recovey mode which has least option reboot, wipe, update zip file, power off. I tried to wipe it but it still stuck, what should I do? everything I searched requires to be at fastboot mode and i can't go to fastboot mode because I can only go to recovery mode any guides on how to install?

Comment: From power-off state, do the fastboot key combination (hold VOLUME- + POWER) until the MI bunny shows up.

Comment: It doesnt work because the rom isnt the stock rom anymore

Comment: Key combos are wired in hardware and will work regardless of what ROM is installed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get ADB to find the device? From a command window, with the device connected via USB, type "adb -d" and see if your device is listed. If it is, type "adb [device] reboot bootloader"